# Comparing numeric values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, integer

I'm under the impression that numeric values are stored as floating points. Comparing floats for equality in any other language is unreliable and not recommended. Is there some magic that goes on behind the scenes to make this work reliably for what would otherwise be integers? I can't find any other reference to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct about numbers in JS being floating point.  Section [4.3.19](http://es5.github.com/#x4.3.19) of the language specification says

> **Number value**
>
> primitive value corresponding to a double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754 value.

Floating point comparison for integers works just fine.  64b IEEE-754 can accurately represent any integer with magnitude less than 2 to the 53rd power (see [ULP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place)).  The problem comes in when you divide, or use `Math` functions that have to approximate results.

If you do need to coerce a result from a floating point operation to the closest integer, use [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round).

["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know about Floating Point"](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#680) has a good discussion of rounding error.

Answer (score 0):

Magic: `parseInt(5) === 5; // true`

> ECMAScript has the following data types: Undefined, Null, Boolean,
>   String, Number and Object. (TODO: explain ECMAScript type system - see
>   also part X - types in:
>   http://www.cs.brown.edu/~sk/Publications/Books/ProgLangs/PDF/all.pdf
>   and http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CategoryLanguageTyping)
>
> ECMAScript numbers are 64-Bit binary floating-point numbers. (For
>   details see [[ECMA-262]](http://egachine.berlios.de/embedding-sm-best-practice/bi01.html#ECMA-262)). SpiderMonkey uses (type-) tagged data
>   values. Integers ∈ [-2^(wordsize-1-1),2^(wordsize-1-1[ may be stored
>   directly in a jsval (bit shifted and tagged). Other ECMAScript numbers
>   are stored indirectly in a double precision floating-point number (the
>   jsval stores a tagged pointer to the double). Integers ∈ [-2^53,2^53]
>   can be stored precisely in a double.[1](http://egachine.berlios.de/embedding-sm-best-practice/bi01.html#ECMA-262)
>
> `[1]` [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About
>   Floating-Point Arithmetic (edited version)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is it cannot represent certain integer numbers which is too big,

for integers, [–9007199254740992, 9007199254740992] (2^53) is acceptable range for accuracy.

Answer (score -2):

If you know that the numbers you are comparing are Integers, then you rather convert them to integer (for example, if they are available as strings, then use `parseInt(value)`) and then compare them as integers itself.

Comment: JavaScript does not have separate types for integers and floating-point numbers. Integers are `Number`s. Floating-point numbers are also `Number`s.

Comment: i understand, but you could treat them as 'int's